# XYChart not displaying series values

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am implementing XYChart; when data is available to load, chart is also loading as shown in screenshot below.
[image]

After chart loading completed it renders as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

When checked with chart instance in browser console, data and series is properly assigned.
Wondering, Please suggest steps to be taken towards resolution.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try and error finally found the reason.

I was setting `data` after `Series` creation which was causing problem.